# "Is a" relationship or, in other words Inheritance

Tags: design, inheritance, polymorphism

Say I define an interface `IAnimal` which has a pure virtual (abstract) method called eat like this:

```
class IAnimal
{
   virtual void eat(Food*) = 0;
};
```

In the future I inherit form `IAnimal` and create different animals. and eventually I find out that some animals need not only food to eat but also other things. Say in my context, (it is easy to imagine it is a game), `Dog`s can eat if there is a `Food` and a `Plate`. `Man`s can eat if there is a `Food`, `Plate`, `Table` and `Chair`. Does this mean that it is wrong to use inherit from `IAnimal`? Can we say that `Dog` and `Man` are not animals as you can not use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to come up with an accurate taxonomy of the real-world objects you want to represent with a class hierarchy is usually not that productive. Your interfaces should represent *functionality* or *behavior* rather than ontological categories, because that's what interfaces are: one or more functions you can call.

In other words, name the interface `IEater` instead of `IAnimal`, and this problem simply disappears, since anything that has an `eat()` method is clearly capable of eating.

Regarding your examples of additional objects, it's possible that `eat(Food, Plate)` is a special case of the more general `eat(Food, Plate, Table, Chair)`, but it's also possible that these are two completely different kinds of eating that shouldn't be lumped together. That depends entirely on what eating means in the context of your application. If they are completely different, don't be afraid to choose more explicit and descriptive names like `IPlateEater` or `IEaterWithTableManners`.

Comment: So you suggest to have completely different interfaces for different  type of  "Eaters". I think if you cannot interchange the implementations such as for `Man` `eat(food)` cannot make sense, then this means `Man` cannot be derived from `IAnimal`, or `IEater`.

Comment: @Narek If I'm reading your comment correctly, yes I would agree with that.